# I am trying to make a calculator with Java and 3 Classes

Tags: java, calculator

I am very new to JAVA Programming and was trying to make a Java Program that consists of 2 classes and an interface. The main class is StartingPoint.java, the other class is Calculate.java and the interface is Equations.java.

So far I have one equation in the Equation.java interface which consists of a simple addition function. I want the program to prompt the user to insert 2 integers and return the added solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my main class called StartingPoint.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StartingPoint {
public static void main (String Hoda[]){

    System.out.println("Please enter two values");

    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);

    Calculate calculator = new Calculate();

    int answer = calculator.add(in.nextInt(a), nextInt(Scanner b));
    System.out.print(answer);
}
}
```

Here is my second class: Calculate.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculate implements Equations {



@Override
public int add(Scanner a, Scanner b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return  (a + b);
}

}
```

And here is my Interface called  Equations.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public interface Equations {
int add(Scanner a, Scanner b);
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I get an error on Calculate.java class on the return (a+b) line. I feel like that is what isn't letting me proceed any further

Comment: Your interface should not accept two scanners. It should accept two `int`s. How your calculator obtains its inputs should not matter to the calculation engine itself. Rather, your `StartingPoint` class should collect two `int`s from the user, and pass them to the calculator.

Comment: You should realize that Java is a word and not an acronym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe want to convert the values into integer...something like this:

```
@Override
public int add(Scanner a, Scanner b) {
    int n1=Integer.parseInt(a.next());
    int n2=Integer.parseInt(b.next());
    return  (n1 + n2);
}
```

I see you are new to java. Take a look at your function:

```
public int add(...
```

java expects this function to return an integer. You are returning a + b, but a and b are instances of the object Scanner, not Integers.
So we have to "transform" the input string into and integer object. Java is a very high level language, so almost every object has plenty of methods that will help us to do whatever we want. In this case, the class Integer has a static method called parseInt(String args) that will parse the given string and check if it is numeric. If it is numeric, it will return an integer. If not, it will throw an exception.
That's why you should validate the input. If you type a non numeric value it will crash.

Comment: Wow! Thank you sooooooo much. I've been spending a whole hour trying to look up solutions on the internet. People like you give me hope! I really appreciate it! If you don't mind, can you walk me through what you changed and how it helps my code?

Comment: okay... so I understand that the parseInt function convert the input into an integer, but what does the a.next() and b.next() do?

Comment: First of all: does it work? I haven't tried it...
Take a look to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: How do you know so many methods off the top of your head?? I find knowing all these methods and functions of Java off the top of your head quiet perplexing? Does it get easier as you code more and more cause right now, I am still wondering if this is the thing for me

Comment: @Mustafa The common functions you use a lot will stick but more than anything you learn the right key words to search for. Just from my experience I found java really hard to begin with then one day it just clicked amd now its the easiest thing in the world

Comment: P.s. are you using an IDE (eg eclipse or netbeans) with a decent autocorrect. If so; remebering the functions isnt nessissary, you just type a dot after the variable and it gives you a list of possible methods (possibly with a description of what they do)

Comment: I do not know all the methods... but the semantics are very descriptive, and if you use an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, it will show you all object members and even its description. After programming a lot, you will start memorizing the methods, but you don't need to.